# Mismatch between scene view and game view

Tags: unity, 2d, collision-detection

In my scene view, it looks like the player is correctly lined up with the map. But when I see it in the game view, it's off. You can see the Game view in the top-middle, and the Scene view in the bottom left. The map sprite in the game view seems to be off by one tile. It could be that the collision is off too.

[image: Example]

What could be causing it and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The camera x rotation is not set to zero.

Comment: Yes it is. Rotation for main camera is (0,0,0). edit: I'm dumb, must be set in a script because it's (0,0,0) when it's resting.

Comment: In the pic it is not (0, 0, 0). See if any of your scripts affect the camera rotation. See the script that makes the camera follow the player.

Comment: Sorry about that -- feel like a total jerk. I was using smoothfollow which is meant for 3d. I switched it with a 2D version.

Comment: No problem we all do mistakes